# Is there any option to set Default value using @Value in java spring properties?

Tags: java, spring, default-value, dto

I am working with Spring to assign a default value for a DTO property using `@Value`.
I have two DTO classes:

```java
public class Student {
  @Value("10") // default value of id should be "10"
  private LookupDTO emp;
  private int totalMark;
  private string sub;
}

public class lookUpDTO {
  private String id;
  private String name;
}
```

How do I assign a default value for `id` as `10` using `@Value`?

Note: `lookUpDTO` is used by other DTO also, so I cannot use `@Value` in `lookUpDTO` directly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If the id property is in fact a value, then yes. You can tell Spring to inject this value or use default.

```
@Value("${some.key:my default value}")
private String id;
```

However, since you want just the default value and not to inject a value, `@Value` annotation is not what you want. Instead you could initialize the id in `LookupDTO` and Spring will replace it with incoming value.

```
public class LookupDTO {
    private String id = "10";
    private String name;

    // get, set, etc...
}
```

If this default value conflicts with other usages you will have to duplicate the class or handle the default value when you read it.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```java
@Value("${some.key:my default value}")
private String stringWithDefaultValue;
```

See [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-defaults) for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Value like this:

```
public class Student {
  @Value("${some.key:10}")
  private LookupDTO emp;
  private int totalMark;
  private string sub;
}
```